# How to copy & paste eclipse package in same eclipse src folder

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I want to reuse `status` package with its sub packages and files to user taxonomy folder by refactoring as userTypes. Despite doing it manually is there any way in eclipse to copy & refactor folder (sub folders & files) that is to reuse package with another name?

Comment: When I copy a Java file into a different package, the package statement gets updated. Is this not the behavior you expect? Otherwise, please tell what you get actual vs. what you expect with an example.

Comment: Its not changing many things e.g. The files imported from same packages are not refactored

Comment: When using _Refactor > Move_ (Alt+Shift+V) you have the option _Update fully qualified names in non-Java text files_. Please improve your question by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since it's still unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ***Refactor > Move*** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) you have the option ***Update fully qualified names in non-Java text files*** for that.